# How do I authenticate API requests (by anonymous user) in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The API requests will be sent by anonymous users. No Login/register functionality is present.

I need to authenticate the API requests, one primitive way I tried was to send an auth key in each request. This auth key, I is saved in the Angular frontend as a constant.

There must be a better and more sophisticated way, kindly help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Django REST framework largely assumes that requests are authenticated based on a user, but they do provide support for authentication anonymous requests. While this largely breaks from the assumption that "authentication" means "verifying a (Django) user is genuine", Django REST framework does allow it to happen and just substitutes the `AnonymousUser` instead.

Authentication in DRF can define both the `request.user` (the authenticated user) and `request.auth` (generally the token used, if applicable) properties on the request. So for your authentication, you would be holding on to tokens you have created (in a model or somewhere else) and those would be validated instead of the user credentials, and you would just end up not setting the user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions

class ExampleAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        auth = authentication.get_authorization_header(request)

        if not auth or auth[0].lower() != b'token':
            return None

        if len(auth) == 1:
            msg = _('Invalid token header. No credentials provided.')
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        elif len(auth) > 2:
            msg = _('Invalid token header. Credentials string should not contain spaces.')
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        try:
            token = Token.objects.get(token=auth[1])
        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such token')

        return (AnonymousUser(), token)
```

This example assumes that you have a `Token` model which stores the tokens that will be authenticated. The token objects will be set to `request.auth` if the request was authenticated properly.

Comment: Note that if a custom authentication returns `None` then `AnonymousUser` will be the default user applied to the request; and if you're using the `IsAuthenticated` permission, an anonymous user won't be authenticated. Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015528/custom-authentication-for-non-user-connection-with-django-rest-framework/50766330#50766330) uses a custom `AnonymousUser` to authenticate a specific device.

Answer (score 0):

Read the rest api docs on [authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) and their [tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/) - they offer a solid intro to the options.

Comment: Thanks, I did look into the docs, all the auth schemes are based on the assumption that the requests originate from a user, is there a way to authenticate requests that do not have any user associated with them?

Comment: Given, “authentication is the process of confirming the identity of a person”, I don't really understand what you mean by authenticating requests that have no identity associated with them?